# Laravel Permission middleware returns 403 Forbidden always

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using the `laravel-permission` extension from Spatie for managing user roles and permissions. I have configured users, roles and permissions and it is updated in the database correctly. Now I am trying to protect the routes using `role` middleware as follows:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Manager']], function () {
      Route::get('/test', function(){
          echo "HERE";
          die();
      });
 });
```

When I access the `test` URL, it is always showing `403 Forbidden` error. I have checked the user roles using `$user->roles()->pluck('name');` and it is returning the following:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1180 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => "Manager"
  ]
}
```

But still I am getting the `403` error. How can I fix this ? I need to add anything to the routes to make the middleware working ?

Comment: can you post that middleware also

Comment: Can you post your route and middleware groups ? and don't forget to run the config:cache

Comment: I have one more middleware at the top like `Route::middleware(['middleware' => 'auth'])->group(function () {`

Comment: We need to see the role middleware or / and if you have a form request

Comment: don't forget to clear permissions cache with the following command:  php artisan permission:cache-reset

Comment: how did you solve that?